# How can I get rid of cats?

Tags: home, pest-control, pets

My previous neighbor started to feed any and every cat that went close to his property, he is no longer around but he didn't take the cats with him.
Currently I have like 4 or 5 cats daily messing with my trash can, pooping in my front floor, not letting us sleep at night doing their cat 'business', destroying my wife's garden.
I don't want to be cruel but I am getting to the point of really considering it.
I live in a place where authorities won't do crap about it! I don't want to adopt any I just want them gone!

Comment: I got a dog for the same reason.

Comment: Buy a cage, trap them with a can of tuna fish, and drive them out in the woods the next day. It works.

Comment: search here who wants to get rid of rats , they may help you about your cat problem :D

Comment: Relevant: (cars, instead of the trash cans) https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/28503/1743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have cat issues, we've tried everything from lion faeces, to sonic devices, and several other things with no luck.

Our solution that has worked 100% so far (on bin bags, outside prior to collection) is diluting 6-7 drops of [citronella oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citronella_oil) in 1ltr of water, with a small amount of dishwashing liquid to emulsify it all together inside a spray bottle (makes it far more miscible).  After spraying generously on and around the area we don't want cats, it has worked brilliantly.

I guess I should add; test it on a small area before spraying it on anything as a precautionary measure against spoiling surfaces or damaging something.  Contact with skin/eyes is probably a bad idea too.

The stuff smells strongly of lemon/citrus, so if you have a dislike to those kinds of smells, then maybe this isn't for you if it's around windows or doors.

Additionally, it won't last forever outdoors if it rains, and will probably need reapplying often, but a small amount diluted does go a long way.

Hopefully that works!  As a side note, and something someone said once, cat's are unlike dogs in that a cat will obey rules even when a person isn't there.  For example, if you only allow a cat to sit outside by a door and never allow it through the door, it will never come in when you're not around.  A dog on the other-hand, probably would :P

Comment: If you train your dog properly, a dog can learn boundaries. My dog never enters the livingroom even when exciting guests are visiting (including other dogs!), and lays on the threshold between the kitchen and the living room as the closest she is allowed. She can only access the hallway and kitchen and outdoors, and never enters the bathroom or laundry room or bedroom all with wide open doors off of the hallway, day or night, when we're home or gone.

Comment: This concept is called an "invisible wall" (unrelated to products sold online - this is pure training not electric collars or anything), and isn't too difficult to train. It's also helpful psychology for the dog to have areas they can't go, helping them know they aren't the pack leader and thus reduces aggression and (possibly) improves obedience.

Comment: I will try this, sounds like it can work.
I don't have cats, I despise them!, and yes as you said my dog obeys boundaries only when i'm around lol.

Comment: @arana - I hope it does work! It's been the saviour cure for us; you just have to see the neighbours' bags along our street to see ours hasn't been touched!  Regarding dog trainability, the dogs' background has a lot to do with its behaviour(rescue, breed, household, environment, etc), and with some dogs, basic commands can take a lot of work not everyone can afford to give in their available time, so don't worry about what your dog can and can't do, that's what doors are for lol. (Dog trainer for 15+ years)

Comment: @Timeless : Will any kind of dishwashing liquid work, or does it have to contain a specific ingredient like amonia or something else? which one do you use? will any 1 dollar store no brand dish soap work?

Comment: @arana - Any kind should do it.  It's use is to purely emulsify the citronella oil into the water as oil isn't miscible.  You don't need much at all, try a couple of drops of dishwashing liquid, mix together; if the citronella oil has disappeared, that's all you need.  Harder water will need more dishwashing liquid.  The own store $1 will work, we use anything we have at hand, I guess even liquid hand soap would work too.

Comment: I'm using pepper, not on the cat, but on the places they want to eat or take or go to.

Comment: Had not had a chance to come back and thank you, that worked for me or at least I believe it did, or maybe the cats found a better place, the thing is I tried this and only noticed after 2 weeks that problem starting fading away.

Comment: @arana Glad it worked for you! We still haven't had any issues with cats (or badgers, foxes, and seagulls) since we started using this citronella solution on our bins/bags a few years ago. All credit goes to my grandmother :D

Answer (score 3):

I found the following somewhere on the internet posted by user daff55odil4:

> Find in your garden where the cat is going to the toilet. buy some balloons and blow them up not too large, dig a hole and bury the balloon. When the cat comes again it will start to dig, the balloon should pop and make a noise hopefully scaring the cat away. no one is hurt.
>   Gail

I have never tried it and am not sure if this works.

Comment: at least sounds fun!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a sonic fence or like device. Some are designed to keep pets in a yard, some are designed to keep pests out with the use of sound that only particular animals can hear and find uncomfortable. This is just a thought. Might need a little research.

Comment: This sounds good, I wonder if it wont affect my poodle.

Answer (score 0):

If you live in town. You should be able to get help locally. Otherwise here's a few tips.

-The most humane way is to purchase a cat trap. Plastic or metal, preferably with a door. ;)

Place some "Bait" (Sardines, tuna or cat food) 
Let the waiting game commence.

Drop them off at the nearest "Pet Humane Society".

-Sprinkle pepper or spray hot sauce in the most common areas.

-Most cats hate water... ;)

-Try finding recordings of dogs barking or growling. See if it scares them off.

Comment: Given that most offending cats will belong to your neighbours.  The local humane society will merely return them to their owners who will report you to the police for trying to steal their cat.

Comment: Lol. Good point. Make sure it's a stray.

Comment: These don't belong to no one, if they disappear no one will miss them. There is no such society here, closest thing is a facebook group. Tried Pepper , didn't work, how am i supposed to WATER them, if i get out they dissapear in seconds, to only come back right after I close the door, there are 2 noisy pitbulls in my neighbor house, plus my inside house dog, they can bark all they want, cats only laugh at them.

Comment: Not in USA. Oh and police couldn't care less for your lost cat here, if its not in your house its your fault it's missing, so no "he stole my cat" works here, at most police would laugh out loud at you if you say that.

Comment: To get them wet, you could set up sprinklers that you can turn on from inside the house. (I don't think that motion-sensitive lawn sprinklers exist, but they should!)

Comment: They do, here is one example (commercial website): https://www.amazon.com/ScareCrow-Motion-Activated-Animal-Repellent/dp/B000071NUS.

Comment: If they dont I can make them easily, not so easy to be aware when the cats go in.